# On $\phi(n)=\phi(n+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I was working on a problem, namely finding natural numbers $n$ such that $\phi(n)=\phi(n+1)$ and I started to make some progress (I think). I wanted to know what work has already been done on this problem.

Looking for it on approach$0$, the only relevant and somewhat useful source I found was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464727) but the only thing it addresses is the values rather than a more general solution, just like the papers I found on the subject on the internet(For reference, the ones I found were either testing values upto some number / giving tables of values/ proving something for a bounded value or paid papers which I cannot afford to pay for). I also looked at references and links on [the OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A001274) and I did not find anything of particular interest to my problem.

More particularly, I am working on a solution to a special case, i.e., when $n$ is prime.

As far as I know, this is an unsolved problem. Please direct me to some sources that address this problem without using any numerical bounds or anything on those lines. If it is unsolved, then I would greatly appreciate if someone guided me as to how I can start writing a paper. I have no mentors who know anything about research, and I am too young to have any professors around me with knowledge about this subject.

Comment: I would have thought the OEIS page should be fairly comprehensive....there are several papers linked to on that page, and presumably each of them has an extensive bibliography.  Though I can't imagine there will be any references which will avoid "numerical bounds or anything on those lines".  That's pretty much all of analytic number theory you are excluding.

Comment: @lulu I did go through those papers and most of them weren't addressing the problem that I am working on. Some of them are value tables, some use a numerical bound in the beginning. None of them really matched what I was looking for.

Comment: Well...we have no idea what you are looking for, as you haven't said very much.  As it stands, I expect people here will just waste their time and yours pointing you to references you have already discarded.

Comment: @lulu RE to your first comment's edit : what I mean by numerical bounds are bounds predetermined, I don't mean bounds which restrict all the results. Like for example, I think it is fairly easy to see that $n$ must be even, and that derivation is a bound that is acceptable, but bounds like "so and so fact holds for $n < x$ " where x is a ludicrously large number. Again I am open to criticism and corrections because I have no experience in research whatsoever. To your second comment : I think I have made it fairly clear that I am looking for primes satisfying the given equation.

Comment: If  $p$ is  an odd prime,  we have $\varphi(p)=p-1$ but $p+1$ is even so $\varphi(p+1)≤\frac {p+1}2$, or am I missing something?

Comment: ...so that makes it obvious that no primes $>3$ can appear on the list.  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @lulu WOW. That was a very quick and crisp answer. Thank you. Could you provide a proof of $\phi(p+1) \leq \frac{p+1}{2}$?

Comment: Half the natural numbers less than $p+1$ are even, hence not relatively prime to $p+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

There are no primes $p>3$ such that $\varphi(p)=\varphi(p+1)$.

Proof:  Indeed, $\varphi(p)=p-1$ but $\varphi(p+1)≤\frac {p+1}2$.  The latter follows since, writing $p+1=2^am$ with $a≥1$ and $m$ odd we have $$\varphi(p+1)=2^{a-1} \varphi(m)≤2^{a-1}m=\frac {p+1}2$$

But of course $p-1>\frac {p+1}2$ if $p>3$, and we are done.

Note:  a similar argument also rules out the existence of primes $p$ such that $\varphi(p-1)=\varphi(p)$, though again one has to take a look at a few small cases.

Comment: I almost feel ashamed that I did not think of that. Thank you. Regarding the note, I'd add that ruling out the second case you mentioned is easier since $\phi(p)=p-1$ but $\phi(p-1)<p-1 \forall p$.

Comment: Good point! $\quad$